# Concatenate the LISTAGG output with other columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g, concatenation

I need to concatenate the outputs in same query. Is it possible to do this?

Example query:

`Concat(c.manames,a.transaction_amt_us) as concat
listagg(i.settlement_type,',')within group (order by i.settlement_type) as settlement_type,`

I want to concatenate both outputs i.e concat and settlement_type and get in one column.

something like:
`Concat(concat,settlement_type)`

Help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.  Just use `||`:

```
(c.manames || a.transaction_amt_us) ||
 listagg(i.settlement_type,',')within group (order by i.settlement_type)
) as AllTogether
```

You can do this with `concat()`, but you need to call it twice:

```
concat(concat(c.manames, a.transaction_amt_us),
       listagg(i.settlement_type,',')within group (order by i.settlement_type)
      ) as AllTogether
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I tried this already but it did not work. I have one used 'listgg' for other column as well but that does not require concatenation. is that the problem?

Comment: I mean there is no data retrieved. Without applying this I get 1635 rows.

Comment: @Prash . . . You should ask another question with your full query.  If you can, set up a small example on SQL Fiddle to demonstrate your issue.  A `concat()` does not filter out rows.  And, editing this question will probably invalidate my answer, which is impolite, so it is better to ask another question (even if you delete this one).

Comment: @Gordon..I have accepted your answer for the question I posted which will work for that part of question. I will post another question with an example for my actual issue which makes sense to post it separately.